# How do I change the display position from absolute to relative?

Tags: css

I am creating a website [here](http://bit.ly/asyVAJ). In the HTML I have two lines:

```
<span class="header_text">Trapped in payday loans?</span>
<span class="header_text2">We can help you!</span>
```

The class `.header_text` and `.header_text2` are defined in css.css with the attribute `position: absolute`.

1. Would it be more professional if I changed CSS position from absolute to relative?
2. How do I change position from absolute to relative?  When I do so the text appears in wrong parts of the page.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using position absolute if it accomplishes the job you're trying to accomplish.  Your header text looks fine... just increase `left:60px;` (try `left:160px`) in both `.header_text` and `.header_text2` css rules.

Comment: Hey read this, this will help you ..http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Absolute_Layouts . Read the relative to what exactly part .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want to achieve, there is no *more* professional, both values serve their purpose but they are different. You cannot just change one for the other.

But if you change `absolute` for `relative`, most likely you have to place the elements in question somewhere else in your HTML to achieve the same effect (if even possible).

[For completeness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position):

> **relative**
>   Lay out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned).  The effect of `position:relative` on `table-*-group`, `table-row`, `table-column`, `table-cell`, and `table-caption` elements is undefined.
>
> **absolute**
>   Do not leave space for the element.  Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

The biggest difference is that elements positioned with `absolute` are taken out of the normal page flow (that is why it is said *do not leave space*).

Answer (score 4):

1. You change it for functionality - neither is more *professional*.
2. `position: relative`. Though it will probably appear in wrong parts of page because its offsets no longer apply.

Answer (score 0):

Always stick to absolute, relative is not very professional and normally dumb people use this just to show off they can use odd layout to impress others.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really make sense. In what way is using `position: relative` not professional?